# How to open notification url with application webview

Tags: android, webview, notifications

As am a beginner to android development, I am working on an application and i want that my application notifications should be opened in a webview. I try to look for ref here but so far i have the following which is opening notification in browser not my webview.

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse(myurl));
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(MachezaMainActivity.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    // Resources r = getResources();
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MachezaMainActivity.this)
            .setTicker("The Macheza")
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image)
            .setContentTitle("yortext")
            .setContentText("sdsd")
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager2 =  (NotificationManager) MachezaMainActivity.this.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager2.notify(0, notification);
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: change your `notificationIntent` in the way which it will open your Activity ... in the activity add the code whoch would be open incoming intetn in the webview ...

Comment: @Selvin am a bigner please show me that, i could hav do it

Comment: *am a bigner please show me that* then you should start by reading official guide (especially about intents) ... because without this anything what I would write is like describing colors to a blind man

Comment: @Selvin But it ll help me go deep.

Comment: @Selvin if possible try to help, thanks.

Comment: @Selvin i changed the intent to **Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,MachezaMainActivity.class);** the app is opening but the webview is not getting the url.. what should i do?

Comment: now read about `Activity.onNewIntent` what is it and how to use it  ... it's android basics ... and it seems like you didn't read about it ...

Comment: Thanks it worked i use **onNewIntent()** and pass new value to static url which is my url to load. i appreciate n' like your teaching... can catch the fish myself now.